# How can i download individual map tiles from the Google Maps SDK (for iOS)?

Tags: ios, google-maps, location-based

I've been checking out the new Google Maps SDK for iOS that allows you to bypass Apple Maps for map related features in your app!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro

The SDK seems fairly easy to use, but i want to know:

1. If it is possible to use the SDK (are there API's) to download individual Map tiles?
2. If so, how?

Ive looked at the documentation given on their developer portal and it says the following:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map

> The key class when working with a Map object is the GMSMapView class. GMSMapView handles the following operations automatically:
>
> 1. Connecting to the Google Maps service.
> 2. Downloading map tiles.
> 3. Displaying tiles on the device screen.
> 4. Displaying various controls such as pan and zoom.
> 5. Responding to pan and zoom gestures by moving the map and zooming in or out.
> 6. Responding to two finger gestures by tilting the viewing angle of the map.

It seems like the downloading of the tiles happens automatically, or are there API's that allow manual access to the tiles?

If not, any workarounds would also help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation and header files do not indicate any way to download individual map tiles.

Even if you would find a workaround, you would not be allowed to use it. See clause 10.1.1 (a) in the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms):

> *No Access to Maps API(s) except through the Service.* You must not access or use the Maps API(s) or any Content through any technology or means other than those provided in the Service, or through other explicitly authorized means Google may designate. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).

Comment: Does that mean i cannot access Map tiles using Googles' web URL's provided for their static maps? And i want to do this for a mobile device? Would that be allowed?

Comment: You can use Google's Static Maps API as long as you follow their terms of service, but that will not, strictly speaking, provide you with individual tiles, so I presumed that you would not like that solution. It is hard to tell unless you explain what you try to achieve. My point is that their terms does not allow you to use  their APIs in other ways than intended.

Comment: I realize that I need to explain what I meant when I wrote that the Static Maps API will not give you individual tiles: One obvious difference is that the static API will embed the Google logo and a copyright statement in the image. You are not allowed to remove them, which means that if you try to glue together several "tiles" of this kind to a larger map, it will look quite ugly and clumsy, besides the fact that it is not allowed. Gluing together tiles to a larger map is what people usually mean when they use the term "tile". But if you have another use in mind, the static API may be useful.